# Basic Spamfilter in Postfix

Tags: postfix-mta, spam-prevention

I need a basic configuration in postfix (*mail_version = 2.6.6*) which can filter spams from any known domain/IP (which are listed in RBL directories). This maybe a duplicate question, but I do not see any effective config options online which will filter spams.

**Note:**
I tried with some configs, but that will filter emails from gmail also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I need a way to test the RBL config made in postfix. A way other than sending an email to "nelson-sbl-test@crynwr.com"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RBLs can be used to stop in the client phase.  I use them to stop bad clients from sending to my domain through my smtp relay in the cloud.

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org, reject_rbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2, permit
```

The client restrictions above check 3 rbl lists.  You can have as many as you want.  The directive `reject_unauth_destination` also won't accept email destined for another domain, unless it comes from a specific list of client IPs (which are listed in mynetworks).  I use other virtual servers and they are allowed to relay through this postfix server.